# resize non-adjacent partitions?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

I have a dual boot with three main partitions, one each for Ubuntu, Windows, and my files. I want to make the one with Windows ("OS") a bit larger, which would have to be at the expense of the one with my files ("BSpace"), but when looking in GParted I find they are not adjacent to each other. Even if I shrink "BSpace" I couldn't extend "OS" into the gap... 
...or can I?

I'm a bit uncertain and don't want to mess up the whole system (even if I have a backup)

All suggestions welcome
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open "File system support" from the Gparted menu, and ensure that the intersection of "Resize" and "ntfs" is checked. If not, then install the ntfs-3g package:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

In some cases, there are very small gaps which cannot be filled. For example, logical partitions are preceded by an Extended Boot Record, which describes the following partition. However, you should be able to fill all of the remaining empty space.